# Populate paramters of Import-Gpo using CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, import, group-policy

CSV:

```
BackupGpoName,BackupId,GPOName,path
"GPO1",11111111-2222-3333-444444444444,"GPO1","C:\BackupGPO"
"GPO2",78888888-1222-4555-8777-123456789123,"GPO1","C:\BackupGPO"
```

Script:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\gpotest.csv" -Header BackupGpoName, BackupId, gponame, Path
$csv | ForEach-Object {
    $params = @{
        BackupGpoName = $_.BackupGpoName
        BackupId      = $_.backupid
        TargetName    = $_.gponame
        Path          = $_.path
    }
    $params.$type = $true
    Import-Gpo @params -CreateIfNeeded
}
```

But I get the error:

```
Foreach-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'BackupId'. Cannot convert value
"BackupId" to type "System.Guid". Error: "Guid should contain 32 digits
with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)."
At line:2 char:10
+   $csv | Foreach-Object {
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ForEach-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

Comment: Read the error then look at your first backupID.

Comment: Don't specify `-Header`. Your CSV file already has a header line in it.

Answer (score 0):

Bill_Stewart is correct you should not specify `-Header` if your csv has the header included.  Using your sample csv and simple print statements:

```
$csv = import-csv -Path "C:\temp\test.csv" -Header BackupGpoName, BackupId, 
gponame, Path
$csv | Foreach-Object {

$_.BackupGpoName
$_.backupid
$_.gponame
$_.path

$params = @{
    BackupGpoName=$_.BackupGpoName
    BackupId=$_.backupid
    TargetName=$_.gponame
    Path=$_.path
}
$params.$type = $true

#import-gpo @params -CreateIfNeeded 
}
```

Results in and error because the code is attempting to cast "BackupId" as a GUID:

`BackupGpoName
BackupId
GPOName
path
GPO1
11111111-2222-3333-444444444444
GPO1
C:\BackupGPO
GPO2
78888888-1222-4555-8777-123456789123
GPO1
C:\BackupGPO`

Since your csv has a header your code should be

```
$csv = import-csv -Path "C:\temp\test.csv"
$csv | Foreach-Object {

$_.BackupGpoName
$_.backupid
$_.gponame
$_.path

$params = @{
    BackupGpoName=$_.BackupGpoName
    BackupId=$_.backupid
    TargetName=$_.gponame
    Path=$_.path
}
$params.$type = $true

#import-gpo @params -CreateIfNeeded
```

}

and the expected output of:

`GPO1
11111111-2222-3333-444444444444
GPO1
C:\BackupGPO
GPO2
78888888-1222-4555-8777-123456789123
GPO1
C:\BackupGPO`